# Copy Galaxy S4 encrypted storage to computer

Tags: data-recovery, samsung-galaxy-s-4, encryption

My dad passed this summer,

he had a galaxy S4 which probably holds many photos I'd like to recover. I tried many passwords to unlock the phone but now it says that if I try two more times it'll erase the phone. The phone seems to require the password before booting. I saw the logo and now a black screen asking for the pass.

There is a good chance I can find the password if I can try multiple ones. Is there a way to:

- Remove the attempt number limit?
- Copy the encrypted storage on my computer and use some tools to try passwords and decrypt it?
- I'm not a 100% sure the S4 has encryption, maybe I can lift the password if it isn't?

A best case scenario for me would be to have a way to test passwords using command line, I'm a programmer and could make a small script to test combinations of passwords and numbers I know he used.

Any help or insights appreciated.

Comment: The S4 is running Android 4.4-5 at that time Android's encryption was pure password based (no hardware anchor). But I am not sure if Samsung had modified the system to use an hardware anchor (if this would be the case off-device encryption would be impossible). Your main problem for off-device decryption is that you can't access the data partition on a bootloader-locked phone. And unlocking the phone erases all data. The only chance would be an exploit in the bootloader or another component that is started before the decryption.

Comment: your comment points out that unless I've got forensic tools, I'm out of luck. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend to try cf-auto-root or tgalal inception and inject some custom init.rc script in boot or system that deletes locksettings.db (or use heimdall for flashing)

Comment: thank you for naming the techs, I will research them and update the thread if it gives me success.

Comment: check out the chipset exynos or qualcomm? https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/rooting-roms/how-to-backup-qualcomm-phone-root-t3570178 https://github.com/bkerler/edl

Comment: https://forensicswiki.xyz/wiki/index.php?title=How_To_Decrypt_Android_Full_Disk_Encryption#Locating_the_Encryption_Key https://santoku-linux.com/howto/mobile-forensics/how-to-brute-force-android-encryption/#run-brute-force